# What format is ~/.aws/credential & config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, format, dataformat, aws-credentials

I was wondering if there was a name for the data format that the AWS credentials and config files are in.

A sample `~/.aws/config` file like this:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1

[profile1]
region = eu-central-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a take on the [INI file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).
However I am not sure if the SDK and eventually configparser in python supports all the conventions of a INI file like the `;` based comments etc.

Comment: Thanks! I tested this out and the AWS CLI (so configparser) does ignore `;` comments. Neat!

Comment: Based on Marcin's answer about it using Python's configparser, [you can also use `#`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure) to begin a comment.

Answer (score 2):

AWS CLI is written in Python, and the format is standard python format supported by its [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html). Not sure if there is any offical name for it, except that it is similar to "Microsoft Windows INI files".